# Pandas Dataframe Multiple column headers, apply function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns headers

I want to apply the below function to only the 2nd column header. Is this possible?

So 2.0 and 2.1 in the below example

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('i', "") 



    header 1.0     header 1.1
    header 2.0     header 2.1
0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with recreate the `MultiIndex` columns and assign back

```
s2=df.columns.levels[1].str.replace('i','')
#good to mentioned here
#since you need the change the 2nd level
#so using .levels is good enough , but if you need do that for 1st level 
#try using `pd.Series(df.columns.get_level_values(1)).str.replace()`
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.get_level_values(0),s2])
```

Comment: thanks alot. I'm getting this error message however; ValueError: all arrays must be same length

Comment: any ideas what this could be?

Comment: @fred.schwartz using `s2=pd.Series(df.columns.get_level_values(1)).str.replace('i','')` as I mentioned in comment